# How to load next web page in perl?

Tags: html, perl

I am trying to learn web development using perl.  I have 3 very simple perl scripts that just print out a text line on each page.  I want hello1.pl to print "hello world" in the browser than run the next script either hello2.pl or hello3.pl depending on the $rc value and load that page in the browser.  I don't think I am doing right thing by using the system command.  How do I do that ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<PAGE;
<html>
<body>
hi to you too<br>
</body>
</html>
PAGE
```

hello3.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<PAGE
<html>
<body>
Good bye cruel world
</body>
</html>
PAGE
```

hello1.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:  text/html\n\n";

print <<PAGE;
<html>
<body>
hello world<br>
</body>
</html>
PAGE

$rc = 0;
if ($rc)
{
  system ("/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/tutorial_perl/hello2.pl");
}
else
{
  system ("/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/tutorial_perl/hello3.pl");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three primary methods to do redirects:

1. Use an HTML Header: [CGI - Generating a redirection header](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI.pm-4.03/lib/CGI.pm#Generating_a_redirection_header)
2. Use a META Refresh: [w3c - Using meta refresh to create an instant client-side redirect](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html)
3. Use JavaScript: [Window Location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

However, honestly, you should just create a link for users to click on.

Comment: Ok thanks Miller.  I was just trying to learn how to redirect a page based on certain condition.